# using an array of class to launch different activities within GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I was reading the exapmle of GridView and I'd like to click on a picture and get an activity running so I tried to change the part related to Toast.... with a kind of class array but I think just got a mess...maybe someone get better result than my idea here's what I tried

```
 public class HelloGridView extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
           setClass(HelloGridView.this, classlist).startActivity(classlist);
       }
    });

    private integer [] classlist = {R.clip1, R.clip2, R.page3};
}
```

I am new to develop app so I just guess how to change this code
Thank you for any suggestion

ANgelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go through the link: http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-3-more-views in that they are describing very well how to implement a grid view, gallery etc. As a fresher in development it helped me a lot.

Comment: Thanks, I had a quick look at link you provided and it's very easy explained. I will try to read the 4 parts before make new attempts cause I miss part of the basis and I wish to learn them asap.  I hope I can tick the answered sign soon. Have a good time. Thanx.

Comment: Thank you I start reading the blog you suggested from the first part and it appears tu be very useful. I already got some results. I wish I can help you in next future.- Bye